# List direct children of page

Tags: posts, php, functions, get-children

I am currently using the following function to list the children of a page, however the function recursively finds children of the children and I only want to list the direct children of `$post->post_parent`.

```
wp_list_pages(array('child_of' => $post->post_parent,'exclude' => $post->ID))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
wp_list_pages(array('child_of' => $post->post_parent,'exclude' => $post->ID, 'depth' => 1))
```

Read [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) for more details.